# How to partition a list into similar average subsets

Tags: python, algorithm

In a list of 300, I need to position 50 items, all repeated 6 times (300 total) in such a way that each item is within a certain range, and the average position of the item in the list is around the middle (150).

By each item in a certain range, I mean the 8 smaller subsets which are positions like:
1-36, 37-73, 74-110, 111-148, 149-186, 187-225, 226-262, 263-300. So, for example, item 1 could have positions 1, 38, 158, 198, 238, 271 in the list, with an average position of 150.6.

I'm trying to do this to automate a currently manual and time consuming process, but I'm having trouble figuring out the algorithm. My current thinking is for each item, randomly position the item into each segment, ensuring that if I choose the minimum position for each subsequent segment, the average cannot be higher than 150(+-2), if it is, randomize the previous position again until a number works. But thinking about it, it seems like it may not work and probably won't be fast. I'd really appreciate any help with this

(coding in Python if it matters)

EDIT:

to clarify, I am trying to position these items randomly, so for example, item1 would not appear 1st in all the subsets (I know that wouldn't make an avg of 150, just for clarification sake). In the example I supplied, item 1 would appear first in the first subset, second in the second subset and 9th in the 3rd. This is actually where I am having trouble

Comment: What's a "good" output here? You can just heuristically do it in a single pass, but you'd improve it with multiple iterations (which is not a simple task). I think this is too broad

Comment: Sorry, a good output here would be a list of 300 items, where each item (e.g. item1, item2, item3) is repeated 6 times in the list and would have an average position within the list of around 150

Comment: This is much better than the previous description; thanks!

Comment: Do you need a random process, or would a deterministic process be suitable ?

Comment: both would be fine, as I could technically just shuffle the list before the algorithm runs to randomize it, but I'm interested to learn how to use a random process, thank you!

Comment: *"such that each item is within a certain range"* are these ranges an input to the algorithm, and is there also an input saying which items are allowed to be in which ranges? You gave an example saying *"the 8 smaller subsets which are positions like..."* but it's not clear whether those ranges are fixed, or inputs, or determined from the other inputs somehow.

Comment: The ranges are fixed and not inputs into the algorithm (for simplicity), they're the ones I've listed

Comment: Would this work https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward by construction.  Let's refer to your 8 slices (subsets) in four pairs.  Note that I've corrected the arithmetic on the slice boundaries.

```
A    1-38 , 264-300    37 slots    first & last
B   39-75 , 226-263    38 slots
C   76-113, 188-225    38 slots
D  113-150, 151-187    37 slots    middle pair
```

More specifically, we will pair there in reverse, mapping locations 1-300, 2-299, 3-298, etc.  Those pairs of elements will receive the same value from the list of 50 items.

Now, we need sets of 6 slices in 3 pairs, distributed evenly.  Each of these sets will omit one of our pairs above:

```
A B C     items  1-12
A B D     items 13-24
A C D     items 25-36
B C D     items 37-48
```

Since we allocate these in strict pairs, we will now have a mean of *exactly* 150.5 for each of the 48 objects, the optimum solution.  Were the quantity of items divisible by 4, we could finish the allocation trivially.  However ...

We now have items 49 & 50 remaining, 12 items.  Slices A & D have 2 pairs open; B & C have 4 pairs open.  We allocate these to sets ABC and BCD, finishing the construction.

Every item is allocated to 6 different slices, and has a mean position of 150.5, the mean of the entire collection of 300.

---

**Response to OP comment**

I never said they were to be placed in order of item number.  Go ahead and do it that way, but only for the lower half of the slices (1-150).

Now, `shuffle` each of those partitions.  Finally, make the upper half the mirror-image of the lower half.  Problem solved -- maybe, depending on your definition of "random".  The first half has high entropy, but the second half is entirely deterministic, given the first half.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer! However, I am trying to make the positioning a little more random than that. If item 1 were to be placed in A, it'd be 1st to be shown for both of those segments, while that is okay every once in a while, if the placement of all items is consistently the same for each item it sort of nulls the experiment I'm trying to do. [I will update my question to reflect this]. In the example I used, the position is more random